# C# Record microphone input and store it in array of bytes instead of local storage

Tags: c#, audio, audio-recording, microphone

I am trying to record my microphone input and instead of saving the recording in a `wav` file in local hard drive I want to store it in array of bytes in real time.

So while I am speaking it would be recording my voice and storing bytes in an array in real time.

Is it possible?

currently the code I am using only records my voice then eventually after I am done with recording it will save it in a file.

and here is the code :

```
        [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "mciSendStringA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        private static extern int mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, string lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);

        // START RECORDING
        mciSendString("open new Type waveaudio Alias recsound", "", 0, 0);
        mciSendString("record recsound", "", 0, 0);

        // STOP RECORDING
        mciSendString(@"save recsound " + "Hello" + ".wav", "", 0, 0);
        mciSendString("close recsound ", "", 0, 0);
```

Comment: Yes you can.  You can store anything into a byte array at real time.  You can also serialize that byte array to a disk or other storage mechanism at any time.  It's all about how your code is structured.  I don't think you providing us enough information to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using task? () Is a Windows Forms application or Webforms? You can create Task using asynchronous. Asynchronous programming.